# Facebook Connect iPhone StreamDialog delegate dialogDidSucceed

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, facebook, fbconnect

I use FBStreamDialog to let users publish on their news feed.

> [fbStreamDialog show];

makes the dialog view popup, the user can press ***cancel*** or ***submit*** that message.

Now...my problem is that both buttons close the dialog view and call the delegate method ***dialogDidSucceed***.

How do I find out which button was pressed?
Its very important for me to know, any useful advice would be reaally really nice!

Thanks, John

Comment: I have never used fbconnect but i want to see how it works send me a demo app if you want to find the solution. I just want to help you ok

Comment: you can only help me if you have used it before (i am not a beginner) but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok... didnt want to give up. just in case somebody else gets the same problem..

if you do not mind making a slight modification to the fbconnect original code - open FBDialog.m and add the following line to -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad...

> [_webView
>   stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('cancel').onclick
>   = function onclick(event) { window.location.href =
>   'fbconnect:cancel'; }"];

this will call the dialogDidCancel delegate method instead the dialogDidSucceed.

cheers.

Answer (score 1):

there should be button index so that you can recognize which button was pressed.

Comment: how do i access that button index ?

this is the delegate method i have to use:
-(void)dialogDidSucceed:(FBDialog*)dialog 

it doesnt provide a button index :-(

Comment: please post complete code or send source code this is my mail id rahul.vyas@isol.co.in

Comment: why??? if you have never seen a facebook dialog view then you cannot help - if yes, the view contains two buttons, cancel + publish. how do you find out which button was pressed??

Answer (score 1):

I asked the facebook connect developer team and got the following answer:

> We don't currently reveal what button
>   the user clicked in order to avoid
>   incentivization of publishing actions.
>   The DidSucceed just lets you know the
>   dialog was run properly, and FB will
>   publish or not publish the story
>   appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, this worked for me.

- (void)dialogCompleteWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
  if (![[url absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"fbconnect://success#*=*"])
  {
   // your msg
  }
  }